# Shared element transition using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

In Android, shared element transition allows 2 exact same elements existing in both pages to link together when transitioning pages, just like the album art in the gif shown below:

[image: Android shared element transition]

I wonder if it is possible to achieve the same kind of transition with ReactJS between classes. If so, any examples? If not, what about with jQuery?

Comment: The transaction you showed should be achievable using one element transition (image + music player) in html5/css3 while the reactjs can manage the content change of the music player sub-element. So that you don't need to find a share element transation alternative in react

Comment: To answer your question directly, have you checked https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup ?

Comment: @ChrisChen Already checked it, I think I'm going to make my own Shared Elements Transition system. In the meantime if someone finds a library that does this already, please link it here.

Comment: @ChrisChen do you have any actual code example?

Comment: Look at examples here https://github.com/joshwcomeau/react-flip-move, https://github.com/bkazi/react-layout-transition and https://github.com/GoogleChrome/flipjs (non-react)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this transition almost entirely with the CSS `transform` property. React JS is all about manipulating the DOM, but you don't need to do that here much.

The animation:

1. Hides the text content of the small panel.
2. Scales the picture and text background to fill full screen.
3. Puts in the new text content.

Of those 1 and 3 are easy with React, so you only really need the transition animation.

Here is a very very basic example using no JS at all:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0: left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
  /* Transition properties mean changes to them are animated */
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.card>img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card>.content {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}


/* This is only for the purposes of this demo.
 * In production you'd have an underlying grid layout and JS to figure out the position */
.card:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 175px;
}

.card:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 230px;
}

.card:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: 230px;
  left: 175px;
}


/* On hover transform the card to full size and translate it to the top left
 * Note that translate comes before scale. */
.card:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  transform: scale(2.1667);
  z-index: 2;
}

.card:nth-of-type(2):hover {
  transform: translate(-175px, 0) scale(2.1667);
  z-index: 2;
}

.card:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  transform: translate(0, -230px) scale(2.1667);
  z-index: 2;
}

.card:nth-of-type(4):hover {
  transform: translate(-175px, -230px) scale(2.1667);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/325/F50057/ffffff">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/325/F44336/ffffff">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/325/1DE9B6/000000">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/325/FFEB3B/000000">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

The basic trick is to use CSS `transform` with `translate` and `scale` - these properties can be handled by the graphics card and so keep animations smooth even on mobile.

Note that the CSS is rather clunky - I've done it like that just to show that it can be done with pure CSS. In practice you're going to want some JS to set the offset properties, hook up a click event, etc.

Another trick (which I haven't done here) is to scale the animation backwards - start with the full size control and `translate`/`scale` it down into the position it appears to start in. When the user clicks on it remove the `transform` - that saves the browser from having to recalculate the full sized object's DOM before starting the animation.

Comment: This is pretty cool! However it doesn't fit my needs. In react the list with the items and the item focused on are two separate components, so I can't to it easily, like shown in your example.

Comment: @Lucio You can, you just need an extra step after the animation plays out to swap in the item component. Or you make the item component handle both the expanded detail and the list view and then it does the transitions. In either case, this is how you do that kind of transition in the web.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly because I am unaware of Android framework. Here is my solution based upon ReactJS knowledge:

Steps:

1. Maintain 2 state variables: `CurrentMode` & `NextMode`. Possible values are `1` & `2`.
2. At the click of album change the `NextMode` to `2`. And in code compare the values of `CurrentMode` & `NextMode`. If `CurrentMode` < `NextMode` than set the size accordingly.
3. Similarly when `CurrentMode` > `NextMode` than set the size accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with mauerwerk: https://github.com/drcmda/mauerwerk

It's basically a grid where each cell gets a status whether it's in thumbnail or opened mode. You can use this status to switch or transition between contents, whether you want to fade them or let parts stand is up to you. There's an additional toggle function which you can use to toggle a cell open/closed.